# Tail recursion and CPS

Tags: scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I pass in a predicate and a list to another function in scheme. If the predicate gives you true, you add it to your answer list, else you skip it.

For example, `(myfilt positive? '(1 -2 3))` should be `(1 3)`. But I have been getting `(1 . 0)`.

```
(define myfilt
   (letrec ([testfilt (lambda (x poly function)
                        (if (empty? poly)
                            (function '())
                            (testfilt x (rest poly)
                                      (lambda (v)
                                        (function (if (x (car poly))
                                                      (cons (car poly) v)
                                                      0))))))]
            [identity (lambda (x) x)])
     (lambda (x poly)
       (testfilt x poly identity))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your innermost `if` should use `v` for the else branch, not 0. Thus:

```
(if (x (car poly))
    (cons (car poly) v)
    v)
```